# Social network integration in Android app, and should i keep user info in table in SQLite?

Tags: android, sqlite, facebook-login, google-signin

I am making an Android app for fitness, it will be my first serious android project  so far. I've made a google sing in feature in my app.
Because when a user is register either with social network or manually with username,password,email - he/she will do stuff once logged into the app. Like, create a workouts, do workouts, have own graph about the progress when doing workouts.

Now, i am not sure about this,I already know how to implement SQLite with tables, when user is register and logged manually.But, i do not understand, what to do with the data when user is logged and/or register with one of the social networks, facebook,google, twitter.

Where should this data be saved?
Can i save in SQLite? 
Should i have a SQLite table specific for the social network?

Comment: As with me, I dont store login info for users from social login. Instead I store profile details of all users and a flag to determine where they came from. And users can login from anywhere and do their stuff

Comment: As it means, once user is logged with social network, to have some detail form that  user needs to enter, and store that info to SQLite, and later fetch that data to the appropriate user?

Comment: I guess whatever detail you ask in normal signup form like email name etc, success message from social login will provide it. Apart from those details, you need to ask them

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can save the values in SharedPrefrence.

Comment: The data from social network to be saved in shared preferences?

Comment: Normally will save the values such as firstname,lastname,email etc in the shared prefrence